# C# Partial class with the same void, is that possible?

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface, blazor

I don't even know how to ask this question to google.
But here's the scenario.
I want to build a few components that my app is using and each component might have to do some DI registration.

What I want to do is create a class 1 and class 2.

Class1.cs

```
public static partial class Register {

   public static void RegisterComponents(this ServiceCollection service)
   {
      //... do work here ...
   }
}
```

and then have a second class in another project

Class2.cs

```
public static partial class Register {

   public static void RegisterComponents(this ServiceCollection service)
   {
      //... do work here for another component...
   }
}
```

Then in my main UI application I want to call.

`services.RegisterComponents();`

Is this possible?

Comment: What happened when you tested it?

Comment: There is no such thing as a _partial class_.  The `partial` keyword allows you to split the definition of a single class into multiple source files.  The mental model for this is that the compiler takes all those source files and combines them into a single class.  In your case, what do you expect to happen if you were to call `services.RegisterComponents();`?

Comment: Make a base class instead with a `virtual` method, then you can override that method in derived classes.

Comment: @Flydog57 - there certainly are partial classes in C#. They just don't exist in IL anymore.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/partial-classes-and-methods

Comment: @ℍℍ: I'm not arguing that the documentation doesn't mention _partial class_ or that people don't say _partial class_ or that source code can't include _partial class_ as if it's a thing.  What I'm saying is that, unlike a _class_ or an _interface_ or a _foreach loop_, this is no such _thing_ as a partial class.  A class declared using the `partial` keyword is the same as any other class, except that its definition is split over multiple source files.  Personally, I think `partial` is a good keyword, but the doc folks at MSFT should have avoided using `partial class` as a noun.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to declare two methods with the same signature in the same class. Using the partial keyword doesn't make any difference. It will lead to a compile error anyway.

Like others have meantioned in comments, the partial keyword is just a way of telling the compiler, that a class definition may stretch over multiple files.

A common usecase for using the partial keyword is code generation. Where one file contains generated code and the other file contains hand written code. This way the generated part can be updated by the code generator without overwriting manually written ones.